# How do I temporarily bypass an alias in tcsh?

Tags: shell, alias, tcsh

I am using tcsh. bash and zsh and other suggestions won't help here.

I have several aliases that are named the same thing as another command, so if I did unalias it, typing the same thing would now do something different.

Most of the time I want the aliased command, which is why I have them. However, sometimes I want the unaliased command.

Without actually unaliasing and redefining the command, is there a simple way to tell tcsh to use the unaliased command instead?

For example, vi is aliased to vim, but sometimes I want to just use vi. cd is aliased to change my window title, but sometimes I want to leave it alone.

Obviously I could type /usr/bin/vi but since cd is a shell built-in command, there is no equivalent. Is there a general solution?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a backslash:

```
% alias ls ls -a
% ls
# ls -a output here
% \ls
# plain ls output here
```

For shell builtins, there turns out to be a gotcha:  a leading backslash prevents both aliases and builtins from being used, but an internal backslash suppresses aliasing only.

```
% alias cd pushd
% cd /tmp
/tmp /tmp 
% c\d
% dirs
~ /tmp
```

(I'm tempted to call that another argument against using the `csh` family of shells.)

Comment: I keep getting "command: Command not found." for command, and "cd: Command not found" for \cd. Is 'command' a tcsh built-in?

Comment: *sigh* POSIX weirdness... there are fakes in `/usr/bin` on here. But the manual confirms that backslash should work... and turns out it does, but you have to quote an *inner* character to prevent aliasing while still supporting builtins. BTW, If you're trying to do something after a `cd`, take a look at `alias cwdcmd` in `tcsh(1)`; this also saves you from having to deal with `pushd`/`popd` etc.

Comment: `command` is usually a built-in in POSIX shells, and needs to be for `command -[Vv]`. Using a backslash to bypass the alias only works for regular commands, not for builtins (because builtins can't be quoted in (t)csh any more than aliases can).

Comment: It seems that command is not available on my system (aside: how did you format that to stand out?), but the internal backslash works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers @geekosaur - I didn't know about this \ behaviour and I think it'll be quite handy as I begin to use aliases more and more frequently. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make aliases that clobber shell builtins. *Your life will be much easier*. There are plenty of key combinations left, try `cw` for your change window title alias :)

**Edit:** Two step solution for fixing alias that aren't yours:

1. Find the monkey who aliased `cd` to something other than the change-directory command and request his transfer to the oped column of the local paper. He shouldn't be holding a job where he can force ideas like that one onto other people's shells!
2. `echo unalias cd >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Some of the aliases I have are not of my own doing. I appreciate your advice and will do my best to heed it where possible. Now that there _are_ aliases I would like to bypass, how do I?

Comment: Sure. `unalias cd`.

Comment: Evidentally, I wasn't clear at all, Caleb, and I apologize. Let's call the 'cd' case solved. I was trying to find out how to do this for other aliases _without_ unaliasing. I'm sorry I did not get that across. It looks like an internal backslash is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The `cd` alias might be setting the title **and** changing directory.  That is a pretty common practice from the days before `precmd` and `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 0):

prefix your command with the word 'command'. Ex.

```
command ls
```

Comment: Does this work in tcsh, as the question requires? Does it work with built-in commands?