# What does `\time`, `t\ime` and `\cd` actually do? (fun with backslashes in shells)

Tags: shell, quoting, posix, time-utility

While discussing over the differences between `/usr/bin/time` and the shell (bash and zsh) built-in `time`, someone mentioned that one can use `\time` as a shorthand to get `/usr/bin/time`.

First it seemed like a nice innocent shortcut, but then some questions came up:

- Why does `t\ime` work too?
- Why does `\cd` change the directory, even though `/usr/bin/cd`¹ does not?

So obviously, `\foo` is not equivalent to `$(which foo)`. The question is now:

Is the observed behaviour of `\foo` in both bash and zsh in any way covered by the POSIX definition of a shell, and if so, why does it behave like it does?

---

Footnote 1: `/usr/bin/cd` is, on my system,

```
#!/bin/sh
builtin cd "$@"
```

Comment: Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/how-do-i-temporarily-bypass-an-alias-in-tcsh Note that \command is specifically documented tcsh functionality that says to ignore aliases for the command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`t\ime` or `\cd` (or `"tim"e` or `'cd'` or `${-##*}time` or `${-+time}` and every other combination of quoting and expansions you could think of that would eventually resolve to `time` or `cd`), is that: another way to write `cd` and `time`.

However, that would eventually resolve to `cd` or `time` at a later time of the shell syntax parsing and interpretation. In particular, that happens long after shell keyword recognition and *alias* substitution take place.

So, at the time the shell is looking for keywords in its language, it is not recognising `ti\me` as the `time` shell keyword. So a:

```
ti\me echo test
```

would be recognised by the shell as a simple command as opposed to the `time` keyword followed by a simple command.

Then the quoting in `ti\me` would be processed (here that backslash is quoting the `m` character which doesn't need quoting anyway, the quoting character is removed, you get `time`) and a `time` *command* would be looked-up like any other commands (in the list of builtins, functions and executable files in `$PATH`. Most likely that will be `/bin/time` here)

For `cd`, there's no `cd` keyword in the shell language, just a `cd` builtin command (which takes precedence over your `/usr/bin/cd`). However, if you do define an alias for `cd` (like `alias cd=pushd`), same again. As alias substitution is done very early, before quote removal, if you have an alias for `cd` and not one for `\cd` (note that not many shells allow aliases with backslashes in them), then by writing:

```
\cd dir
```

you're making sure your `cd` alias is not substituted.

In short, quoting a command name or any part of it prevents it from being seen as a shell keyword (keywords being things like `while`, `for`, `if`, `{`... `time` is a keyword in *some* shells only), and bypasses an alias you may have for it.

It does not however force that command to resolve to an executable file in `$PATH`, the command is still searched first among *functions* (which you can work around by doing `command time cmd...`) and *builtins* (which you can work around by doing `env time cmd...`, though I don't know of a shell that has a builtin `time` command).

Note that quoting can also have an influence on the behaviour of the special builtins of the `typeset`/`declare`/`export`/`local`... family in some shells. See [Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?](/q/97560) for details.

Comment: So, the difference between ``time`` and ``cd`` which leads to the difference in observed behaviour is that ``time`` is a *keyword* and ``cd`` is a *builtin command*?

Comment: @JonasWielicki, it's that `time` is a keyword and that `cd` is not. (and if you had an alias for `cd` or `time`, that would be another matter). That `cd` is builtin or not has no incidence at this point (as far as the influence of quoting is concerned). Some shells however have a few builtins that are halfway between keywords and builtins as their parsing is done differently from other builtins. That's the case of `export`/`typeset`/`declare`. I should probably add some note about it in this answer.